# Getting the handle of an empty textbox

Tags: .net, vb.net, pinvoke

I'm trying to control another .NET application from my .NET application. But I'm having trouble getting the handle of a specific textbox.

Up until this point I have been iterating through the main forms child windows and checking the value returned by the GetWindowText() Windows API method to see if I have the correct control. But the program I'm trying to control has 2 empty textboxes, they both have the same class and they both return the same value from GetWindowText(). So I can't identify the textbox that I need to get the handle of.

Is there anyway to get the name of the control? I read a bit about using SendMessage with 'WM_GETCONTROLNAME' but I couldn't find that much about it.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [Inspect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318521(v=vs.85).aspx) can help you accomplish this task easier.

Comment: @HanletEscaño Thanks for your suggestion. I have been using Spy++ and Ranorex spy to view details about the controls. Spy++ like Inspect does not show the name of the control, however Ranorex Spy does, so there must be some way to get the name of the control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this by using the Microsoft UI Automation library.

I created a function which iterated through the child windows and created an AutomationElement from their handle which allowed me to check the ID / name of the control. Once I found the control I was looking for I returned it's handle.

```
Public Shared Function getHandleByID(ByVal windowHandle As IntPtr, ByVal ID As String) As IntPtr
    For Each window As IntPtr In GetChildWindows(windowHandle)
        Dim aE As AutomationElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(window)
        If aE.Current.AutomationId = ID Then
            Return New IntPtr(aE.Current.NativeWindowHandle)
        End If
    Next
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Having done the work with UI Automation, why would you want the window handle. UI Automation can read the text for you.

Comment: @David There will be more stuff going on other than just reading text. One of the things I need to do is changing the parent of a control.